# Ruby character .ord and .chr

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, char, special-characters

When I `.ord` a non-english character, and then with the same integer try to convert it back to a char with `.chr`, why do I get different results?

e.g.

```
'Ø'.ord # => 216
216.chr # => "\xD8"
puts 'Ø' # i get: Ø
puts 216.chr # i get: �
```

Comment: Copying it over from the duplicate for convenience: `216.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`